# Reloading .Xresources colors on the fly

Tags: spacemacs, themes, x-resources

I use [pywal](https://github.com/dylanaraps/pywal) on Linux which is really cool and works on everything I use except for Firefox (gotta tinker with it) and (GTK) Emacs.
For Emacs the author recommends [this](https://github.com/cqql/xresources-theme) which is awesome but requires me to restart Emacs whenever I change my wallpaper (and my global colorscheme).
For terminal Neovim with the wal vim theme it just works, I reload my colorscheme and wallpaper and the terminal AND Neovim change colors, but for Emacs I must restart it for it to use the new .Xresources, which is a PITA since I use Spacemacs.
Now I'd like to know if there's any way at all to make Emacs reload it's .Xresources data on the fly (if there isn't any way then I'll seriously consider switching full-time to Neovim because with some configuration it can be really, really good. One thing I really like about it is the terminal, lightyears better than `ansi-term`)

Answer (score 2):

**PART-1: modifying `xresources-theme.el`**

The problem with `xresources-theme.el` is that it uses `x-get-resource` to get the `Xresources` colors and it doesn't refresh (even if `.Xresources` has been updated using `xrdb`) until `emacs` is closed and restarted.

So my solution relies on parsing `.Xresources` file directly. To do this replace the function `xresources-theme-color` in `xresources-theme.el` with the following:

```
(defun xresources-theme-color (name)
  "Read the color NAME (e.g. color5) from the X resources."
  (shell-command-to-string (format
                "xrdb -q | grep \"%s\" | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d \"\\n\""
                   (concat "*\\(.*\\)" name ":")))
  )
```

Now you can reload the `xresources-theme.el` using `M-x load-file /path/to/file/xresource-theme.el`.

(*CAUTION:* The above code uses `grep` which can be tricky as different users have different styles while writing `.Xresources` and `grep` can end up matching to something not intended. So you would have to customize the `grep` part in a manner that is appropriate for your `.Xresources`. Also, I will like to hear about any ideas you have about how to make `grep` command more universal in above.)

**PART-2: (optional) using `SIGUSR1` for hot-reloading `xresources-theme.el`**

Add the following to your `.emacs`

```
;; SIGUSR1 to reload config files
(defun sigusr1-handler ()
  (interactive)
  (load "xresources-theme.el"))
(define-key special-event-map [sigusr1] 'sigusr1-handler)
```

Now you can hot-reload `xresoures-theme.el` by executing `kill -USR1 $(pgrep emacs)` at `bash` prompt.

(One takes a similar approach to reload the config for `URxvt` as in this [github-project](https://github.com/regnarg/urxvt-config-reload).)

(*CAUTION*: Sane thing to do: make sure you have `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/path/to/xresources-theme")`in your `.emacs`)

**PART-3: (optional) suggested workflow**

I would recommend creating a bash script called `apply-themes.sh` with the content:

```
#!/bin/bash

xrdb .Xresources 
kill -1 $(pgrep urxvt)
kill -USR1 $(pgrep emacs)
```

and use it to update your `.Xresources` so that `URxvt` and `emacs` get updated along with it as well. If you use `pywal` or similar you could still adapt your workflow to accomodate the above.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

(Sept 9, 2022's Edit: p.s.: Been years and no up-votes yet! :( Please up-vote if useful.)